# remove content between a specific character and whitespace

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string in python of floats that looks like this:

```
"a b c,d e"
```

And I would like to efficiently change it to this:

```
"a b c e"
```

The original string is a line in a text file and there may be more than one comma in the string. I.e. every time there is a comma I want to remove all characters between it and whitespace. I could do this with a for loop, make a list, and then join that list with a whitespace character, but I need to do this many times so speed is important. Hopefully using regular expressions.

Just to be clear a,b,c,d and e are not characters they usually look like 1.00e-03 or something.

Comment: It would help to have the actual constraints on what `a`, `b`, etc. can be.

Comment: @murgatoid99 Right, sorry. They are all either integers or floats formatted as 1.00e-03. I think that something like "a,b,c d" could occur too (multiple commas per section), if that is relevant. Thanks!

Comment: And in the case of multiple commas, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this;

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "a b c,d e"
>>> re.sub(r',\S+', '', s)
'a b c e'
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just to make sure \S means replace a non-whitespace character and the + means repeat until failure?

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "a b c,d e"
re.sub(re.search(r'(,\w)', text).group(1), '', text)
>> "a b c e"
```

Comment: You should add some explanation of how you got to the solution so OP and others can learn from your work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need more speed as a simplest way you can use `split` :

```
>>> s="a b c,d e r ,y g k"
>>> sp=s.split(',')
>>> sp
['a b c', 'd e r ', 'y g k']
>>> new=[i[1:].strip() for i in sp[1:]]
>>> new
['e r', 'g k']
>>> new_string=sp[0]+' '+' '.join(new)
>>> new_string
'a b c e r g k'
```